# How to include OpenCV library into a project on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, c++11, raspberry-pi

I installed OpenCV on Raspberry Pi4

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Now I open a project in Qt and in main.cpp include

```
 #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
 //or - the same result
 //#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Qt sees the directory and files in it. But when I compile I get a lot of errors in the opencv library files. Why? May be I should include it in the *.pro file - LIB+= ????? - what should I include?

The errors I get

> -1: error: main.o: in function `cv::String::~String()': -1: error: main.o: in function` cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)'
> :/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:672: error: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
> -1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Have you installed the python opencv packages? pip install opencv-python

Comment: Is your project in C++? If so, please add that tag. Are you trying to compile a program? If so, please add the minimal program. Are you compiling something? If so, please add the command you used. Thank you.

Comment: do I need opencv-python? I plan to write my code in C (Qt). After sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev I see in usr/include/ opencv2 folder in a lot of files. Are the packages installed? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your make file has the correct CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. I recommend:

```
CFLAGS+=`pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LDFLAGS+=`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Here is a quick test that I did:

`test.cpp:`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {}
```

```
nir@jamal:~ $ g++ test.cpp -o test
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccriAyaZ.o: in function `cv::String::~String()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccriAyaZ.o: in function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x30): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

nir@jamal:~ $ g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --libs opencv`
nir@jamal:~ $
```

By adding the correct libraries to the linker using `pkg-config --libs opencv` I was able to eliminate the errors.

Note:
Use `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` not `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` (`<>` instead of `""`) since `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` installs the header files for the system, not in your local directory - even though using `""` search for the system files in case local file "opencv2/opencv.hpp" does not exist, it is better practice to make sure you include the system installed version.

Comment: It doesn't work. But I found the solution - LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs

Comment: I posted too early. Here is the complete solution.

Comment: Note that `$(...)` is more modern and preferable to the backticks you have around your `pkg-config` commands.